# Converting Make to CMake with external libraries

Tags: c, makefile, cmake, aws-iot

Sorry i'm new to make and CMake but I'm trying to convert this example AWS IoT make into CMake. I've managed to do most of it apart from the inclusion of the mbedTLS library. It looks like there is a sub-make of that library and then it gets included.

Any clues would be appreciated, or further reading on the subject.

```
#This target is to ensure accidental execution of Makefile as a bash script will not execute commands like rm in unexpected directories and exit gracefully.
.prevent_execution:
    exit 0

CC = gcc

#remove @ for no make command prints
DEBUG = @

APP_DIR = .
APP_INCLUDE_DIRS += -I $(APP_DIR)
APP_NAME = subscribe_publish_sample
APP_SRC_FILES = $(APP_NAME).c

#IoT client directory
IOT_CLIENT_DIR = ../../..

PLATFORM_DIR = $(IOT_CLIENT_DIR)/platform/linux/mbedtls
PLATFORM_COMMON_DIR = $(IOT_CLIENT_DIR)/platform/linux/common

IOT_INCLUDE_DIRS += -I $(IOT_CLIENT_DIR)/include
IOT_INCLUDE_DIRS += -I $(IOT_CLIENT_DIR)/external_libs/jsmn
IOT_INCLUDE_DIRS += -I $(PLATFORM_COMMON_DIR)
IOT_INCLUDE_DIRS += -I $(PLATFORM_DIR)

IOT_SRC_FILES += $(shell find $(IOT_CLIENT_DIR)/src/ -name '*.c')
IOT_SRC_FILES += $(shell find $(IOT_CLIENT_DIR)/external_libs/jsmn -name '*.c')
IOT_SRC_FILES += $(shell find $(PLATFORM_DIR)/ -name '*.c')
IOT_SRC_FILES += $(shell find $(PLATFORM_COMMON_DIR)/ -name '*.c')

#TLS - mbedtls
MBEDTLS_DIR = $(IOT_CLIENT_DIR)/external_libs/mbedTLS
TLS_LIB_DIR = $(MBEDTLS_DIR)/library
TLS_INCLUDE_DIR = -I $(MBEDTLS_DIR)/include
EXTERNAL_LIBS += -L$(TLS_LIB_DIR)
LD_FLAG += -Wl,-rpath,$(TLS_LIB_DIR)
LD_FLAG += -ldl $(TLS_LIB_DIR)/libmbedtls.a $(TLS_LIB_DIR)/libmbedcrypto.a $(TLS_LIB_DIR)/libmbedx509.a -lpthread

#Aggregate all include and src directories
INCLUDE_ALL_DIRS += $(IOT_INCLUDE_DIRS)
INCLUDE_ALL_DIRS += $(TLS_INCLUDE_DIR)
INCLUDE_ALL_DIRS += $(APP_INCLUDE_DIRS)

SRC_FILES += $(APP_SRC_FILES)
SRC_FILES += $(IOT_SRC_FILES)

# Logging level control
LOG_FLAGS += -DIOT_DEBUG
LOG_FLAGS += -DIOT_INFO
LOG_FLAGS += -DIOT_WARN
LOG_FLAGS += -DIOT_ERROR

COMPILER_FLAGS += $(LOG_FLAGS)
#If the processor is big endian uncomment the compiler flag
#COMPILER_FLAGS += -DREVERSED

MBED_TLS_MAKE_CMD = cd $(MBEDTLS_DIR) && make

PRE_MAKE_CMD = $(MBED_TLS_MAKE_CMD)
MAKE_CMD = $(CC) $(SRC_FILES) $(COMPILER_FLAGS) -o $(APP_NAME) $(LD_FLAG) $(EXTERNAL_LIBS) $(INCLUDE_ALL_DIRS)

all:
    $(PRE_MAKE_CMD)
    $(DEBUG)$(MAKE_CMD)
    $(POST_MAKE_CMD)

clean:
    rm -f $(APP_DIR)/$(APP_NAME)
    $(MBED_TLS_MAKE_CMD) clean
```

This is what I have so far.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(Gateway)

include_directories("${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}" "external_libs/jsmin" "platform/linux/mbedtls" "platform/linux/common" "include")

set(SOURCE_FILES subscribe_publish_sample.c)

file(GLOB IOT_CLIENT_SOURCES "src/*.c")
file(GLOB IOT_CLIENT_EXTERNAL_SOURCES "external_libs/jsmn/*.c")
file(GLOB PLATFORM_SOURCES "platform/linux/mbedtls/*.c")
file(GLOB PLATFORM_COMMON_SOURCES "platform/linux/common/*.c")

add_executable(Gateway ${SOURCE_FILES} ${IOT_CLINT_SOURCES} ${IOT_CLIENT_EXTERNAL_SOURCES} ${PLATFORM_SOURCES} ${PLATFORM_COMMON_SOURCES})
```

https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-embedded-C

Comment: In CMake [add_subdirectory](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_subdirectory.html) can be used for process `CMakeLists.txt` in that directory too. Probably, you need to use that command.

Answer (score 1):

Aprox folder structure:

```
aws_iot
 | - embedded C sdk folders
 | - .... 
sample
 | - include
     | - aws_iot_config.h
 | - src
     | - subscribe_publish_sample.c
```

Original Makefile (updated version)

```
.prevent_execution:
    exit 0
#This target is to ensure accidental execution of Makefile as a bash script will not execute commands like rm in unexpected directories and exit gracefully.

CC = gcc

#remove @ for no make command prints
DEBUG=@

APP_DIR = .
APP_INCLUDE_DIRS += -I $(APP_DIR)
APP_NAME=subscribe_publish_sample
APP_SRC_FILES=$(APP_NAME).c

#IoT client directory
IOT_CLIENT_DIR=../../aws_iot_src
IOT_INCLUDE_DIRS += -I $(IOT_CLIENT_DIR)/protocol/mqtt
IOT_INCLUDE_DIRS += -I $(IOT_CLIENT_DIR)/protocol/mqtt/aws_iot_embedded_client_wrapper
IOT_INCLUDE_DIRS += -I $(IOT_CLIENT_DIR)/protocol/mqtt/aws_iot_embedded_client_wrapper/platform_linux
IOT_INCLUDE_DIRS += -I $(IOT_CLIENT_DIR)/protocol/mqtt/aws_iot_embedded_client_wrapper/platform_linux/common
IOT_INCLUDE_DIRS += -I $(IOT_CLIENT_DIR)/protocol/mqtt/aws_iot_embedded_client_wrapper/platform_linux/openssl
IOT_INCLUDE_DIRS += -I $(IOT_CLIENT_DIR)/utils

PLATFORM_DIR = $(IOT_CLIENT_DIR)/protocol/mqtt/aws_iot_embedded_client_wrapper/platform_linux/openssl
PLATFORM_COMMON_DIR = $(IOT_CLIENT_DIR)/protocol/mqtt/aws_iot_embedded_client_wrapper/platform_linux/common
IOT_SRC_FILES += $(IOT_CLIENT_DIR)/protocol/mqtt/aws_iot_embedded_client_wrapper/aws_iot_mqtt_embedded_client_wrapper.c
IOT_SRC_FILES += $(shell find $(PLATFORM_DIR)/ -name '*.c')
IOT_SRC_FILES += $(shell find $(PLATFORM_COMMON_DIR)/ -name '*.c')

#MQTT Paho Embedded C client directory
MQTT_DIR = ../../aws_mqtt_embedded_client_lib
MQTT_C_DIR = $(MQTT_DIR)/MQTTClient-C/src
MQTT_EMB_DIR = $(MQTT_DIR)/MQTTPacket/src

MQTT_INCLUDE_DIR += -I $(MQTT_EMB_DIR)
MQTT_INCLUDE_DIR += -I $(MQTT_C_DIR)

MQTT_SRC_FILES += $(shell find $(MQTT_EMB_DIR)/ -name '*.c')
MQTT_SRC_FILES += $(MQTT_C_DIR)/MQTTClient.c


#TLS - openSSL
TLS_LIB_DIR = /usr/lib/
TLS_INCLUDE_DIR = -I /usr/include/openssl
EXTERNAL_LIBS += -L$(TLS_LIB_DIR)
LD_FLAG := -ldl -lssl -lcrypto
LD_FLAG += -Wl,-rpath,$(TLS_LIB_DIR)

#Aggregate all include and src directories
INCLUDE_ALL_DIRS += $(IOT_INCLUDE_DIRS) 
INCLUDE_ALL_DIRS += $(MQTT_INCLUDE_DIR) 
INCLUDE_ALL_DIRS += $(TLS_INCLUDE_DIR)
INCLUDE_ALL_DIRS += $(APP_INCLUDE_DIRS)

SRC_FILES += $(MQTT_SRC_FILES)
SRC_FILES += $(APP_SRC_FILES)
SRC_FILES += $(IOT_SRC_FILES)

# Logging level control
LOG_FLAGS += -DIOT_DEBUG
LOG_FLAGS += -DIOT_INFO
LOG_FLAGS += -DIOT_WARN
LOG_FLAGS += -DIOT_ERROR


COMPILER_FLAGS += -g
COMPILER_FLAGS += $(LOG_FLAGS)
#If the processor is big endian uncomment the compiler flag
#COMPILER_FLAGS += -DREVERSED

MAKE_CMD = $(CC) $(SRC_FILES) $(COMPILER_FLAGS) -o $(APP_NAME) $(LD_FLAG) $(EXTERNAL_LIBS) $(INCLUDE_ALL_DIRS)

all:
    $(PRE_MAKE_CMD)
    $(DEBUG)$(MAKE_CMD)
    $(POST_MAKE_CMD)

clean:
    rm -f $(APP_DIR)/$(APP_NAME)
```

Converted CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(sample)


# Setup appropriate path to C SDK
set(AWS_IOT_ROOT_DIR ../aws_iot)

#IoT client directory
#> IOT_CLIENT_DIR=../../aws_iot_src
set(IOT_CLIENT_DIR ${AWS_IOT_ROOT_DIR}/aws_iot_src)

#> IOT_INCLUDE_DIRS += -I $(IOT_CLIENT_DIR)/protocol/mqtt
#> IOT_INCLUDE_DIRS += -I $(IOT_CLIENT_DIR)/protocol/mqtt/aws_iot_embedded_client_wrapper
#> IOT_INCLUDE_DIRS += -I $(IOT_CLIENT_DIR)/protocol/mqtt/aws_iot_embedded_client_wrapper/platform_linux
#> IOT_INCLUDE_DIRS += -I $(IOT_CLIENT_DIR)/protocol/mqtt/aws_iot_embedded_client_wrapper/platform_linux/common
#> IOT_INCLUDE_DIRS += -I $(IOT_CLIENT_DIR)/protocol/mqtt/aws_iot_embedded_client_wrapper/platform_linux/openssl
#> IOT_INCLUDE_DIRS += -I $(IOT_CLIENT_DIR)/utils
include_directories(
    ${IOT_CLIENT_DIR}/protocol/mqtt
    ${IOT_CLIENT_DIR}/protocol/mqtt/aws_iot_embedded_client_wrapper
    ${IOT_CLIENT_DIR}/protocol/mqtt/aws_iot_embedded_client_wrapper/platform_linux
    ${IOT_CLIENT_DIR}/protocol/mqtt/aws_iot_embedded_client_wrapper/platform_linux/common
    ${IOT_CLIENT_DIR}/protocol/mqtt/aws_iot_embedded_client_wrapper/platform_linux/openssl
    ${IOT_CLIENT_DIR}/utils
)


#> PLATFORM_DIR = $(IOT_CLIENT_DIR)/protocol/mqtt/aws_iot_embedded_client_wrapper/platform_linux/openssl
set(PLATFORM_DIR ${IOT_CLIENT_DIR}/protocol/mqtt/aws_iot_embedded_client_wrapper/platform_linux/openssl)

#> PLATFORM_COMMON_DIR = $(IOT_CLIENT_DIR)/protocol/mqtt/aws_iot_embedded_client_wrapper/platform_linux/common
set(PLATFORM_COMMON_DIR ${IOT_CLIENT_DIR}/protocol/mqtt/aws_iot_embedded_client_wrapper/platform_linux/common)

#> IOT_SRC_FILES += $(IOT_CLIENT_DIR)/protocol/mqtt/aws_iot_embedded_client_wrapper/aws_iot_mqtt_embedded_client_wrapper.c
#> IOT_SRC_FILES += $(shell find $(PLATFORM_DIR)/ -name '*.c')
#> IOT_SRC_FILES += $(shell find $(PLATFORM_COMMON_DIR)/ -name '*.c')
file(GLOB IOT_SRC_FILES
    ${IOT_CLIENT_DIR}/protocol/mqtt/aws_iot_embedded_client_wrapper/aws_iot_mqtt_embedded_client_wrapper.c
    ${PLATFORM_DIR}/*.c
    ${PLATFORM_COMMON_DIR}/*.c
)

#MQTT Paho Embedded C client directory
#> MQTT_DIR = ../../aws_mqtt_embedded_client_lib
set(MQTT_DIR ${AWS_IOT_ROOT_DIR}/aws_mqtt_embedded_client_lib)

#> MQTT_C_DIR = $(MQTT_DIR)/MQTTClient-C/src
set(MQTT_C_DIR ${MQTT_DIR}/MQTTClient-C/src)

#> MQTT_EMB_DIR = $(MQTT_DIR)/MQTTPacket/src
set(MQTT_EMB_DIR ${MQTT_DIR}/MQTTPacket/src)


#> MQTT_SRC_FILES += $(shell find $(MQTT_EMB_DIR)/ -name '*.c')
#> MQTT_SRC_FILES += $(MQTT_C_DIR)/MQTTClient.c
file(GLOB MQTT_SRC_FILES
    ${MQTT_EMB_DIR}/*.c
    ${MQTT_C_DIR}/MQTTClient.c
)

#TLS - openSSL
#> TLS_LIB_DIR = /usr/lib/
#> TLS_INCLUDE_DIR = -I /usr/include/openssl
set(TLS_INCLUDE_DIR /usr/include/openssl)
find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED openssl)

# this just for debug purpose
message("OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR is  ${OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR}")
message("OPENSSL_LIBRARIES is  ${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES}")


#Aggregate all include and src directories
#> MQTT_INCLUDE_DIR += -I $(MQTT_EMB_DIR)
#> MQTT_INCLUDE_DIR += -I $(MQTT_C_DIR)
#> INCLUDE_ALL_DIRS += $(IOT_INCLUDE_DIRS) 
#> INCLUDE_ALL_DIRS += $(MQTT_INCLUDE_DIR) 
#> INCLUDE_ALL_DIRS += $(TLS_INCLUDE_DIR)
#> INCLUDE_ALL_DIRS += $(APP_INCLUDE_DIRS)
include_directories(
    include
    ${TLS_INCLUDE_DIR}
    ${MQTT_EMB_DIR}
    ${MQTT_C_DIR}
) 


#> SRC_FILES += $(MQTT_SRC_FILES)
#> SRC_FILES += $(APP_SRC_FILES)
set(SOURCE_FILES
    ${IOT_SRC_FILES}
    ${MQTT_SRC_FILES}
)


#> MAKE_CMD = $(CC) $(SRC_FILES) $(COMPILER_FLAGS) -o $(APP_NAME) $(LD_FLAG) $(EXTERNAL_LIBS) $(INCLUDE_ALL_DIRS)
add_executable(subscribe_publish_sample src/subscribe_publish_sample.c ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(subscribe_publish_sample ${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES} )
```

Take a look at this CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(sample)

# Define correct path to embedded C sdk
set(AWS_IOT_ROOT_DIR  ../aws_iot)
set(IOT_CLIENT_DIR  ${AWS_IOT_ROOT_DIR}/aws_iot_src)
include_directories(
    ${IOT_CLIENT_DIR}/protocol/mqtt
    ${IOT_CLIENT_DIR}/protocol/mqtt/aws_iot_embedded_client_wrapper
    ${IOT_CLIENT_DIR}/protocol/mqtt/aws_iot_embedded_client_wrapper/platform_linux
    ${IOT_CLIENT_DIR}/protocol/mqtt/aws_iot_embedded_client_wrapper/platform_linux/common
    ${IOT_CLIENT_DIR}/protocol/mqtt/aws_iot_embedded_client_wrapper/platform_linux/openssl
    ${IOT_CLIENT_DIR}/utils
)

set(MQTT_DIR ${AWS_IOT_ROOT_DIR}/aws_mqtt_embedded_client_lib)
set(MQTT_C_DIR ${MQTT_DIR}/MQTTClient-C/src)
set(MQTT_EMB_DIR ${MQTT_DIR}/MQTTPacket/src)

include_directories(
    ${MQTT_EMB_DIR}
    ${MQTT_C_DIR}
)


set(TLS_INCLUDE_DIR /usr/include/openssl)
include_directories(
    include
    ${TLS_INCLUDE_DIR}
)

set(PLATFORM_DIR ${IOT_CLIENT_DIR}/protocol/mqtt/aws_iot_embedded_client_wrapper/platform_linux/openssl)
set(PLATFORM_COMMON_DIR ${IOT_CLIENT_DIR}/protocol/mqtt/aws_iot_embedded_client_wrapper/platform_linux/common)
file(GLOB IOT_SRC_FILES
    ${IOT_CLIENT_DIR}/protocol/mqtt/aws_iot_embedded_client_wrapper/aws_iot_mqtt_embedded_client_wrapper.c
    ${PLATFORM_DIR}/*.c
    ${PLATFORM_COMMON_DIR}/*.c
    )

file(GLOB MQTT_SRC_FILES
    ${MQTT_EMB_DIR}/*.c
    ${MQTT_C_DIR}/MQTTClient.c
    )

set(SOURCE_FILES
    ${IOT_SRC_FILES}
    ${MQTT_SRC_FILES})

find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED openssl)

add_executable(subscribe_publish_sample src/subscribe_publish_sample.c ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(subscribe_publish_sample ${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES} )
```

Comment: This is a ton of bare code, which won't really be helpful to the OP without explanation. Please add some human readable definition of what you're proposing.